# How to style Syncfusion SfDateTimeRangeNavigator Xamarin control?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

While working with Syncfusion Xamarin.Forms control, I found it impossible to change background color of `SfDateTimeRangeNavigator` control. Setting `BackgroundColor` property did not helped much - it only change the color of left and right border.

Even more, I tried to set `Content` of `SfDateTimeRangeNavigator` with custom chart (as described  [in documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatetimerangenavigator/content))

```
<rangenavigator:SfDateTimeRangeNavigator Minimum="4/25/2016" Maximum="5/7/2016">
  <rangenavigator:SfDateTimeRangeNavigator.Content>
    <chart:SfChart>
      <chart:SplineSeries ItemsSource=...>
        ...
      </chart:SplineSeries>
    </chart:SfChart>
  </rangenavigator:SfDateTimeRangeNavigator.Content>
</rangenavigator:SfDateTimeRangeNavigator>
```

but it does not work because this code shows empty range navigator control.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: We are able to set chart as content. Check for getting started  document, try this tutorial http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatetimerangenavigator/rangenavigator

Comment: @GobiM, can you share working example? With example from Syncfusion documentation, I still get empty control. See my gist https://gist.github.com/dikyyn/ef109dcbc067e62654b8f05f96527921

Comment: Ref this sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/155686/ze/ChartSample-1075451907

Comment: @GobiM, thanks! Now I now how to style `Content` for `SfDateTimeRangeNavigator`: `((SfChart)RangeNavigator.Content).BackgroundColor = Color.Purple`. Do you know how to change the background color of footer and header as well? I mean top and bottom parts of `SfDateTimeRangeNavigator`.

Comment: Major and Minor scale styles used to change the text colors and there is no direct property for BGColor. Ref: http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatetimerangenavigator/minorandmajorscale#appearance-customization

Comment: @GobiM, thanks a lot for your answers. Possibility to change styles of major and minor scales should be definitely available in future releases of `SfDateTimeRangeNavigator` control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @GobiM for help, here I summarized available options for styling `SfDateTimeRangeNavigator` control:

- replace default chart with custom series:

  ```
  var series = new ColumnSeries{...};
  ((SfChart)RangeNavigator.Content).Series.Clear();
  ((SfChart)RangeNavigator.Content).Series.Add(series);
  ```
- styling Content property of SfDateTimeRangeNavigator, since it is SfChart control ([more here](http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/getting-started)):

  ```
  ((SfChart)RangeNavigator.Content).BackgroundColor = Color.Purple;
  ```
- styling minor and major scales ([more here](http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatetimerangenavigator/minorandmajorscale#appearance-customization)). Changing background color of minor and major scales is not available for now (as of version 14.1.0.46)